# how to merge 2 files in linux

Tags: linux, awk

I have
file 1:

```
line1
line2
line3
....
```

file 2:

```
date1
date2
date3
...
```

and the result should be:

```
line1, date1
line2, date2
line3, date3
...
```

Is there a way on linux with awk (I think) to do that job on command line?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `awk`

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[NR]=$0;next} {print a[FNR]", "$0}' file1 file2
line1, date1
line2, date2
line3, date3
...., ...
```

`FNR==NR {a[NR]=$0;next}` when reading first file `fil1`, store it in array `a`
`{print a[FNR]", "$0}` print out array `a` using line number as index and data from  `file2`

Comment: thanks, and how can change this to make  `line1, date1   line2,date1   line3,date1` . I am newbe to awk

Comment: @WalterSchrabmair You realise Jotne is the person who commented on the other answer telling you to post a new question don't you ?

Comment: @Jotne Please could you explain the awk statement? I am newbe and want to learn. It works great.

Comment: @JID I will do post a new one, in 90 mins. (time span to be allowd to.)

Comment: @WalterSchrabmair See my comment.  `FNR==NR` is a function used to handle more than one file with `awk`. Not easy to explain in a simple go.

Comment: @Jotne thanks I got it. Now I know to answer my sec question: ` awk 'FNR==NR {a[NR]=$0;next} {print a[1]", "$0}' file1 file2 `  Right?

Comment: @JID Not needed.  There are many other example out there, just do google.

Comment: @WalterSchrabmair Yep thats right, nice work !

Comment: @JID thanks yes I got it. Great, awk is a great tool. Must improve!

Comment: @WalterSchrabmair   `printf ("%s, %s ", a[FNR], $0)` should write it without line breaks

print always adds a newline. printf does not

Comment: I´ve read now u were talking about line1->date1 line2->date2. Though it was about one line output. not the relation 1-1, 2-1, 3-1. Sorry. Anyway will leave the comment!!!

Comment: @AlejandroTeixeiraMuñoz thanks yes that are 2 diff problems. THanks a  lot, for your advices! Great help

Answer (score 4):

`paste` command will do:

```
paste -d, file1 file2
```

Comment: Not a big problem, but this does not give space after `,`

Comment: @Blue Moon thanks  alot. I jsut realized that I have also following problem: FILE1:  `line1 line2 line3` and FILE2: `date1`  Result should be date1 merged to each line of file1. Is also there a solution?

Comment: @WalterSchrabmair yes there is

Comment: @WalterSchrabmair Seem to be a different question, so post a new one.

Comment: @JID can you tell it me? Sorry that I posted it to the same question. But it belongs to the same problem

Comment: @WalterSchrabmair Nope, post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this solves your query.
Tweak this code as per your requirement.

```
 paste <(awk 'BEGIN { FS=":";OFS="\t";ORS="\n\n"} { print $1 } END{}' file1.txt) <(awk 'BEGIN { FS=":";OFS="\t";ORS="\n\n"} { print $1 } END{}' file2.txt) >file3.txt
```